# Javascript package or plugin to create network diagrams with IPs

Tags: javascript, networking

Is there a plugin or a package where I can create visual network diagrams like in cisco packet tracer, so that our technicians can request their network schedule per customer.

I have already seen protovis and infovis go by, but it can not do what I really want.

What I actually want is something like the picture.

If you need more information, let me know and if the question is wrong, do not hesitate to correct me.

thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Essential Diagram EJ 2 for JavaScript](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/diagram) supports creating any kind of diagram with SVG nodes and connectors including Network Diagrams.

[Example](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/demos/diagram/network-diagram/)

[image: Essential Diagram based Network Diagram]

The UI for displaying the network diagram can be implemented using Essential Diagram, but the code for discovering your network would have to come from another piece of software.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.